# UICollectionView: Update Section FooterTitles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit

I use a UICollectionView for a Messenger UI. The section footers display the time when a message was sent. However, I only want to display it, when the previous message was sent more than 15 minutes ago.

Therefore, I want to refresh the footers every time a message is sent. However, how can I achieve a refresh of the Section Footer Titles?

I tried `self.collectionView.reloadData()`, however, it does not update the footers (set them to ""). (When I scroll up and down, they disappear, so the logic works.)

Do you know how to refresh the footer titles?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are setting your collectionView like this

[image]

You are using a default flow layout. so you can add labels to both header and footer. and in footer label, set it tag to 1001 (or any number you like).

The identifier of header is "header" , and footer is "footer".
The UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader is defined in flow layout class (check documentation.)

[image]

Now you can reload you header and footer like this:

```
override  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView{
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader ?  "header": "footer"), for: indexPath)
// Configure the cell
return cell
}
```

When you try to change the content of labels in footer, you don't need to refresh the footer. You can call the following anywhere in your application. I call it form  a cell to run the test for convenience
.

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
let footView =   collectionView.supplementaryView(forElementKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 1))
    if let label =  footView?.viewWithTag(1001) as? UILabel{
    label.text = "AnyThing"
    }
```

Here i am using  IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 1), which is the second section.
Now you see the result.

[image]

This is a most simple example. CollectionView can be very complicated and worth a book for all kinds of applications and examples. Hope this can help you.